# Will Azure SQL still charge if I don't consume all DTUs that I have allocated?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using the Azure SQL (non-managed) Standard plan on 10 DTUs.

If I bump it up to 200 DTUs, the estimated costs hit $300+. However, if I don't use them will it still charge me that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is Yes.

If you want different behavior, consider using Serverless pricing model:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose

Comparison of Provisioned vs Serverless:

https://vitalidedkov.medium.com/azure-sql-database-configuration-standard-dtu-vs-vcore-provisioned-vs-vcore-serverless-6158776b4784